# Забота с XML файлом

Tags: java, xml, sax

Добрый день господа!
Сталкнулся вот с каким вопросом.
Есть XML файл вот такого вида:
[image]
И есть код метода который складывает значения в сущность Employee:

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
    if(thisElement.equals("Employee")){
        em = new Employee();
    }
    if(thisElement.equals("age")){ 
        em.setAge(new Integer(new String(ch, start, length)));
        System.out.println(em.getAge());
    }
    if(thisElement.equals("name")){
        em.setName(new String(ch, start, length));
        System.out.println(em.getName());
    }
    if(thisElement.equals("gender")){
        em.setGender(new String(ch, start, length));
        System.out.println(em.getGender());
    }
    if(thisElement.equals("role")){
        em.setRole(new String(ch, start, length));
        System.out.println(em.getRole());
        list.add(em);
        em = null;
    }
}
```

На выходе получается вот такой результат:

Employee{id: 0, age: 29, name: Pankaj, gender: Male, role: Java Developer}
Employee{id: 0, age: 35, name: Lisa, gender: Female, role: CEO}

А теперь вопрос: 
Подскажите мне пожалуйста как мн едотянуться до id  в Employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методу [startElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes)) передаётся список атрибутов.

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if(qName.equals("Employee")) {
        String employee_id = attributes.getValue("id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Именно то что нужно.